# How to rotate video in QVideoWidget in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside, qvideowidget

GUI

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'facebio.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QVideoWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 500, 500))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Main

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia

from GUI import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.mediaPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.widget)
        # fileName = "/path/of/your/local_file"
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("./KakaoTalk_20210818_171950283.mp4")
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(url))
        self.mediaPlayer.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm testing PyQt5 QVideowidget and I'm having a problem with the video rotating.

The videos I found on the internet didn't have rotation, so I didn't have any problems.

But I'm having trouble rotating the video I took with my phone in QVideowidget.

[image]

I didn't turn my phone, I just grabbed it and took the video

[image]

In this way, the video taken by QVideoWidget comes out lying down.

[image]

As you can see, the video is lying down and I want to rotate this video, is there any way to do it?

I don't want to edit the video information. If there is a way to rotate the media, I would like to have the image information and rotate the media using an if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use QGraphicsVideoItem:

```py
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._gv = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self._scene)

        self._videoitem = QtMultimediaWidgets.QGraphicsVideoItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._videoitem)

        self._player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(
            self, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface
        )
        self._player.stateChanged.connect(self.on_stateChanged)
        self._player.setVideoOutput(self._videoitem)

        file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "KakaoTalk_20210818_171950283.mp4")
        self._player.setMedia(
            QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file))
        )
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Play")
        button.clicked.connect(self._player.play)

        self.resize(640, 480)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self._gv)
        lay.addWidget(button)

        self._videoitem.setRotation(90)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.State)
    def on_stateChanged(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self._gv.fitInView(self._videoitem, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self._gv.fitInView(self._videoitem, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another possible option is to use Video QML with QQuickWidget:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtQuickWidgets

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


class VideoWidget(QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setResizeMode(QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget.SizeRootObjectToView)
        qml_filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_filename)
        self.setSource(url)
        self.resize(640, 480)

        self.rootObject().setProperty("orientation", 90)  # 90 or 270

    @property
    def source(self):
        return self.rootObject().property("source")

    @source.setter
    def source(self, url):
        self.rootObject().setProperty("source", url)

    def play(self):
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(
            self.rootObject(), "play", QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = VideoWidget()
    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "KakaoTalk_20210818_171950283.mp4")
    w.source = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
    w.play()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtMultimedia 5.15

Video {
}
```

Comment: In the method using QGraphicsVideoItem, fitInView only works for resize.. 
On_stateChanged doesn't work even if I run the if statement elsewhere.